# Invalid classificationField when updating symbology via ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology, classification, categorized-renderer

I'm new to defining symbologies via ArcPy. I have some code (snippet below) that identifies broken links in .aprx files, sets a new data source & refreshes the symbology data range of this new dataset to display as required.

I have multiple map frames in my layout, which the code loops through, with only one iteration shown below. Each map frame uses a different field from the feature class to display, hence the use of the dictionary.

```
mffldDict = {mfList[0]: scoreFlds[0],
            mfList[1]: scoreFlds[1],
            mfList[2]: scoreFlds[2],
            mfList[3]: scoreFlds[3]}

for eachMF in mfList:
    lyr = m.listLayers("*")[0]
    print("lyr: {0}".format(lyr))

    if not lyr.isFeatureLayer:
        lyr = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(lyr, "memory/lyrFL")

    sym = lyr.symbology

    if hasattr(sym, "renderer"):
        if sym.renderer.type != "GraduatedColorsRenderer":
            sym.updateRenderer("GraduatedColorsRenderer")
            print("sym.updateRenderer = GraduatedColorsRenderer.")
        else:
            print("sym.renderer.type is already GraduatedColorsRenderer.")

        colorRamp = p.listColorRamps("Red to Green")[0]
        sym.renderer.colorRamp = colorRamp

        sym.renderer.classificationField = mffldDict[eachMF]
        sym.renderer.classificationMethod = "DefinedInterval"

        if mffldDict[eachMF] == scoreFlds[0]:
            print("scoreFlds[0]: {0}".format(scoreFlds[0]))
            sym.renderer.breakCount = 10
            if (int(sym.renderer.breakCount) & 1):
                sym.renderer.breakCount+=1
            breakVal = int(totalMin) + 1
            for brk in sym.renderer.classBreaks:
                brk.upperBound = breakVal
                brk.symbol.size = 5
                brk.symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB": [0, 255, 255, 255]}   # null colour for symbol outline

                print("brk.upperBound: {0}".format(brk.upperBound))

                breakVal+=1
```

When I run the above code, I get the error:

```
ERROR: Invalid classificationField : Total_Score
```

This is the correct field name & is type DOUBLE so I cannot see why this field would be invalid. It is not joined from another table or feature class, as I've seen some potential solutions to other similar problems suggest this.

Comment: You only ever get the first layer from your map with this line `lyr = m.listLayers("*")[0]` and then overwrite it if it is NOT a featurelayer, was that your intention?

Comment: Yes - I'm referencing the correct layer & the correct field, as the latter is stated in the error code. I just do not know why the field is apparently invalid.